# Error: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v5.0 were not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, ide, omnisharp

I've installed VS code to build simple examples while I learn .net 5 and c# 9. But VS code doesn't recognize .net sdk 5. I can create new console projects as net 5.

however I don't use properties like these;
viewing problems in problems section
right click > peek definition

I've searched solution for this on the net and I did things below;
setting "omnisharp: select project > my current project"
reinstalling .Net SDK 5,
changing omnisharp path,
changing "use global mono" property as "always"

I have left Output screen below, you to more understand:

> [fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v5.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

> [warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager Failed to load project file 'c:\Users\ilyas\Desktop.Net Notes.Net 5 and C# 9\Basics\Basics.csproj'.
> c:\Users\ilyas\Desktop.Net Notes.Net 5 and C# 9\Basics\Basics.csproj
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1177,5): Error: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v5.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

> [fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager Attempted to update project that is not loaded: c:\Users\ilyas\Desktop.Net Notes.Net 5 and C# 9\Basics\Basics.csproj

P.S. I am new to english, sorry for grammar rules

Comment: You've **twiced** been told to install the "Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack)" - have you done that ??

Comment: I have already installed .net 5 sdk then I've reinstalled it after I've got this error

Comment: OK - but **did you** download the specific package mentioned here  - the "SDK / Targeting Pack" ??

Comment: I find out what you meant now. "SDK/Targeting Pack" already is net 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I figured out why I get this error. I've installed targeting framework, however "vs code" tries to get ".net 5 sdk which is within VS 2019 community". I've upgraded VS 2019 community, which solved my problem.