# VS Code - The reference assemblies for ".NETFramework,Version=v5.0" were not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, .net-5

I have a problem with VS Code .net 5 settings.

```
Error MSB3971: The reference assemblies for ".NETFramework,Version=v5.0" were not found. You might be using an older .NET SDK to target .NET 5.0 or higher. Update Visual Studio and/or your .NET SDK.
```

Some time ago I was using .net core 3 recently I wanted to move to the newest version.

1. I have installed the latest version of the SDK -> https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0
2. I updated VS Code to the latest version
3. I started a brand new project in .net 5

I was looking for a solution to my problem on the internet, but nothing works.

**Powershell dotnet version:**

```
dotnet --version
5.0.401
```

```
dotnet --info   
Zestaw .NET SDK (odzwierciedlenie dowolnego pliku global.json):
 Version:   5.0.401
 Commit:    4bef5f3dbf

Środowisko uruchomieniowe:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19043
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.401\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.10
  Commit:  e1825b4928

.NET SDKs installed:
  2.1.700 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.801 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

**Visual Studio Code Version:**

```
version: 1.60.2
```

[Info about Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a91Ih.png)

**The contents of the project.csproj file**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I have the latest SDK and VS Code, I don't know what else I can do to make it work.

---

I uninstall all versions of .net and install only 5.0.
Now i have new error

```
error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found.
```

---

After I reinstall .NET I got this from terminal:

```
dotnet --info
Zestaw .NET SDK (odzwierciedlenie dowolnego pliku global.json):
 Version:   5.0.401
 Commit:    4bef5f3dbf

Środowisko uruchomieniowe:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19043
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.401\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.10
  Commit:  e1825b4928

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The reference assemblies for framework .NETCore, Version=v5.0 were not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49268779/the-reference-assemblies-for-framework-netcore-version-v5-0-were-not-found)

Comment: Weird, there is no .Net Framework version 5!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v5.0 were not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66194936/error-the-reference-assemblies-for-netframework-version-v5-0-were-not-found)

Comment: Please edit your *.csproj file in a notepad and check whether the very first line is :
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
If yes, then double-check you've installer the Aspnet Core version of the sdk here
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0

Comment: @Romka I have: 
`.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]`

`.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]`

Comment: @phuzi I have the latest versions of VSCode and .NET. And this is recommended to be fixed in this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I struggled with this problem for a long time. Here is a list of things that need to be checked.

1. **Remove all SDKs from your computer.** - Find in the control panel "Programs and Features" then delete all `Microsoft .NET Runtime - x.x.xx`, `Microsoft .NET SDK x.x.x`
2. **Install newest .NET SDK and Runtime** - i use [this site](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0)
3. **Check your PATH** - Check if the path with the environment variables in windows contains `C:\Program Files\dotnet`
4. **!! Check MSBuildSDKsPath Environment Variable** - It turned out that installing the new SDK does not change the information in the environment paths. I still had the old version listed there and after uninstalling everything, I got a message saying that `'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' could not be found.`

   Check the value of the **MSBuildSDKsPath** variable. The proper value for me was x `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.401\Sdks` [image: Environment Variable]

Answer (score 5):

In my case that was caused by global.json in a root folder that had lower SDK hardcoded. Probably worth to add this to previous answer.

Comment: Unbelievable, but true! I copied global.json to the D: drive root and started to see the same.

Comment: Wow... this answer fixed at least 3 completely independent issues around using .net with visual studio, vscode, vscode extension. Just because of a global.json file I put in C:\ folder. Thank you!

Comment: Even though I had a global.json file that specified .net6, in the root of the project, it still overruled those settings by a global.json that was 3 folders up.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the bin, obj and .vs folder and then opening and building the application worked for me.